# what causes eclipse to check (or not check) xml files?

Tags: xml, eclipse, validation

I have two versions of the same project. In one project part of the java source is in a library, which makes testing difficult. So I created a second version of the same project, where all the source is included.
Both projects have identical xml files in their data part in WebContent.
In the library version of the project eclipse complains about some xml files with: "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed" because it does not have a root node. Something we may have to fix.
But to my surprise in the non-library version of the project the same file is present, and here eclipse does NOT complain. How can that be?
Both projects use the workspace settings, so no project specific settings. I compared many settings, but they are all identical. The files have no xml-schema.
Does anybody have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution myself.
 I thought both projects were identical, but that was not exactly true.
 In examining the .project files, I found that the project that showed the xml errors had

```
<buildCommand>
 <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
 <arguments>
 </arguments>
</buildCommand>
```

and the other project had not. After searching the internet for validationbuilder I found that this is indeed the xml checker.
 Having it present in the .profile, forces all xml files to be validated after each build and/or change, causing a red cross on the faulty files.
 In the other project, the same files had the same errors, and when 'validate' was done manually on such a file, the file would show the same error. But it would not automatically show after each build.
 Removing this buildcommand from the .project, does not remove the red crosses, because they have already been detected. They can only be cleared by fixing the error and running validate manually.
 An alternative is to remove from the workspace the file:
 .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects\myproject.markers
 This will reset all red crosses, until the next explicit validation.

Answer (score 0):

Set Eclipse->Preferences->Validation->XML-> Validating file : to "Ignore" (both drop downs) and check also in this area if projects from within the same workspace have different configurations.

Comment: If you look at eclipse->preferences, you have the general setting that applies to all projects. Whatever the setting there, it will have identical result on identical files. Or am I missing something?<br>Both projects use the general settings, i.e. no project specific configuration which might be different.

Comment: By the way, this is eclipse 3.5. under Validation I only find 'XML Validator, which does not have a dropdown that could be set to "Ignore".

Comment: Don't you have something like this : http://marginnotes2.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/xml-validation-in-eclipse/ ?

Comment: loan: that must be a newer version of eclipse, because I don't see the option 'missing root element' <ignore>. Furthermore I only see the top box marked 'validating files'. Not errors/warnings. And again: these are the general settings, applicable to both. So how or when can they give different messages on identical files?